# iOS - Cannot create GPUImageView programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

I'm creating a simple GPUImageView. Here is my code:

```
    GPUImageView *gpImageView = [[GPUImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"];
    GPUImagePicture * inputImage = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:image];
    [inputImage processImage];
    [inputImage addTarget: gpImageView];
    [self.view addSubview:gpImageView];
```

My app crashes on this line:

[image]

I am running on iPhone 6+ and my iOS version is 8.3
Xcode version 7.1

I remember running this code on iOS 9.1 and it works.

UPDATE

I just tested this with the simulator iOS 8.3 iPhone 6 and it works.

Answer (score 1):

For iOS 8.3 you can do something like below as per :

https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/issues/2041

In Method `+ (BOOL)supportsFastTextureUpload` in `GPUImageContext.m` do something like this:

```
float version = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
NSString* formattedVersion = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.01f", version];
if ([formattedVersion isEqualToString:@"8.3"]) {
  return NO; // https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/issues/2041
} else {
  return (CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreate != NULL);
}
```

Hope it will help :)

Comment: As pointed out above, iOS 8.3 (and only iOS 8.3) had a bug that rendered texture caches unusable. I should probably build in a check for this, but I keep forgetting.